# Update appropriate object properties inside array using ArrayFilters and receiving changes with Stream changes Watcher

Tags: mongodb

Did anyone update Document with **ArrayFilters** and listen to changes inside the Collection using stream changes watcher?

The issue is when I update specific properties inside one object in array of objects per Document using **arrayFilters** later in **stream watcher** in `UpdatedFields` of `updateDescription` JSON I receive all fields of this object, while I updated only few of them.

And my question is how can I get only updated Fields.

For example:
I have collection **questions**:

```
{
   _id: <question_id>,
   text: <question_text>,
   author: <author_id>,
   answers: [
                { id: 1560962918255, readBy: [], likedBy: [], author: <author_id>, text: <answer_text> },
                { id: 1560962976840, readBy: [], likedBy: [], author: <author_id>, text: <answer_text> },
                { id: 1565625317539, readBy: [], likedBy: [], author: <author_id>, text: <answer_text> },
                { id: 1565625328764, readBy: [], likedBy: [], author: <author_id>, text: <answer_text> }
            ]
}
```

here is mine `uploadOne` query, where I add `user_id` into arrays **readBy** and **likedBy** of 2 specific answers (ids: `1560962918255` and `1560962976840`):

```
QuestionsSchema.updateOne(
{ _id },
{ '$set':
   { 
     'answers.$[a1560962918255].readBy': '5ced9e11aa9f7a280fc5e79e',
     'answers.$[a1560962918255].likedBy': '5ced9e11aa9f7a280fc5e79e',
     'answers.$[a1560962976840].readBy': '5ced9e11aa9f7a280fc5e79e'
   },
},
{ upsert: false,
  arrayFilters:
   [ { 'a1560962918255.id': 1560962918255 },
     { 'a1560962976840.id': 1560962976840 }
   ]
}
)
```

After this update stream watcher provide me such updates inside `updateDescription`:

```
"updateDescription":
   {"updatedFields":{
      "answers":[
         {"likedBy":["5ced9e11aa9f7a280fc5e79e"], "readBy":["5ced9e11aa9f7a280fc5e79e"], "id":1560962918255,"text":"text 1", "author":"5ced9e11aa9f7a280fc5e79e"},
         {"likedBy":[], "readBy":["5ced9e11aa9f7a280fc5e79e"], "id":1560962976840,"text":"text 2", "author":"5cffc9cdc2ded906ff980f94"}
      ]
   }
```

As you can see each answer includes not only updated fields **likedBy** and *readBy**, but also id, text and author, which I didn't update.

Appreciate any ideas how to avoid receiving not updated Fields or can I replace usage of `ArrayFilters` on something else.